# После разворачивания удалённые из массива данные снова доступны

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Следующая ситуация. В контроллере Ангуляра «вертится» прослушка стрима, которая при получении данных выполняет ряд действия, запросов и в конечном итоге вносит в массив полученные элементы.

```
var source = new EventSource("https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
var stuff = JSON.parse(event.data);
...
$scope.array.unshift(new_el);
}
```

Массив этот выводится пользователю в listView. При клике по элементу с ним выполняется ряд действий, а сам элемент из массива удаляется.

```
$scope.array.splice($scope.array.indexOf(elem), 1);
```

Всё работает. При сворачивании и последующем разворачивании браузера в listView вносятся элементы, которые были получены в свёрнутом состоянии. Но. Иногда (достаточно редко) браузер вместо них начинает сыпать давным давно удалёнными элементами. Которых вроде как и не должно существовать уже в массиве.

В чём тут может быть проблема? Куда копать?

Comment: Ваши данные приходят в массив как объекты. Значит в массиве хранятся не скаляры, а ссылки на объекты. Если элементы массива где-то присваивались другим переменным, то удаление из массива удаляет только одну из ссылок на объект, но не объект. Например, если элементы (для вывода) присваивались приватному массиву в классе, то перебор этого массива выдаст вам старые элементы

Comment: @DmitryKozlov у меня вывод — это обычный ng-repeat с «arr in array track by $index». И происходит такая проблема только после разворачивания, и то не всегда. То есть это что-то нестабильное. Как можно попробовать отловить описанную вами проблему? В console.log($scope.array) только нужные данные. Хотя ng-repeat в любом случае ведь берёт их только оттуда.